# Azure App Registration - custom client secret - is that possible?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-cli

Can I provide my own  client secret either from the portal or via command line - while adding a New Client Secret?

[image: New Secret]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, If you want to create a new client secret just use the --append parameter with [`az ad app credential reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-credential-reset)

```
az ad app credential reset --id "<application id or object id>" --password "stackoverflowrocks!"
```

Comment: The --password option is no longer available.  However you can use the New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075017/azure-app-registration-client-secrets-expiration