# Azure App registration Client secrets expiration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, secret-key

Has Microsoft changed the expiration date for Client secrets to be max 2 years? It is not possible to select "Never" anymore?

Comment: I think the error message hints that secrets should no longer be used but rather certificate credentials: `AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys are expired. Visit the Azure Portal to create new keys for your app, or consider using certificate credentials for added security`

Comment: There is a feedback request to allow for extension of expirations without having to reset the passwords. Please upvote it as it would be a nice way to solve the issue of having to go through all apps using a secret every few years: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c9d2da85-8be2-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. You can set add a credential using Powershell which is more than 2 years. So I'm guessing it's a UI limitation.

```
$startDate = Get-Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddYears(98)
$aadAppsecret01 = New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId b09d3e1b-417d-425c-be05-9e46943d7207 -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
```

Comment: This is the right answer in my opinion. I would just point out that there is another parameter to give the secret a name:  -CustomKeyIdentifier "clientSecret"

Comment: Is the -Value used to give the client secret a value, which we then use to authenticate within Azure function applications (along with the app id)?

Comment: This answer works very well because even if you have an expired secret you can create a new one with the same value by using the -Value parameter.

Comment: Just from a security perspective, this would be very bad practice. Secrets for app registrations should better be handled by the companies secret management system and should not be valid for longer than 1 month.

Answer (score 7):

> Has Microsoft changed the expiration date for Client secrets to be max
> 2 years? It is not possible to select "Never" anymore?

That's correct. The new expiration age for the client secret can be 2 years maximum.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. Can I read upcoming updates and changes for Azure anywhere?

Comment: For Azure AD, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new

Comment: I foresee a lot of production disruptions in two years time. This could be the next form of "certificate has expired" class of problems :)

Comment: @GauravMantri I cannot find any explanation for this change in the link you pasted here, neither any update for april 2021.

Comment: Is there a way to create an alert for an upcoming expiration? I've been looking into policy to see if there is a way to track it. Anyway to at least remind folks that this needs to be addressed.

Comment: @GauravMantri can you post a citation for your assertion that the expiration age for the client secret is a maximum of two years please? I can set it to more than 2 years using PS (see my answer below.)

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars ... I have pinged a member of Azure Identity team regarding this. They would be the best person to answer.

Comment: @GauravMantri have they answered?

Comment: @MartinH it isn't, as it is already bad practice to have an expiration time of 1 year. You should manage your app registrations secrets with an external secret management system and have no more than 1 month expiration or even better create secrets on demand. Everything else is just a big rabbit hole of security issues...

Answer (score 2):

As of February 2022 it isn't possible anymore:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/client-secret-expiration-now-limited-to-a-maximum-of-two-years/

Comment: Via Powershell New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential I can(should I?) specify 10 years

Comment: To access the Microsoft Graph, without a **Ticking-Time-Bomb-2-Year-Key** use: Tutorial: Access Microsoft Graph from a secured .NET app as the app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we got an official answer from Microsoft's team at Jun 08, 2021, according to this discussion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/422538/future-plans-of-microsoft-with-the-maximum-expirat.html

This was the final answer from their engineering team:

> There are plans to limit lifetimes of the secret administratively. However, there are no current timelines or ETAs of when this will happen. Removing the UX option to have never expiring secrets is a first step of that process (you can still create secrets that never expire with PowerShell, AZ CLI and Graph API).

So, I understood that, for a while, I can use PowerShell's method suggested by Daniel [in the accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505809/8249330).
However, we cannot rely on this forever because sooner or later the 'never' option may disappear completely if Microsoft's plans materialize. I hope it doesn't in this case. As some have said, I also foresee expiration problems in the coming years because of this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date through Azure Built in CLI.
Open the Azure CLI in the browser. Then this command below. Note: If you don't pass a password, this will reset your existing password! The end-date is whatever you want it to be:

```
az ad sp credential reset --name {name of your AD app} --end-date 2035-03-04 --credential-description DescriptionHere
```

If you want to preserve the App Secret, which is what I needed, I already had created the secret and started using it, make sure to pass the existing password.

```
az ad sp credential reset --name {name of your AD app} --password {whatever password you want to keep} --end-date 2035-03-04 --credential-description AppAccess
```

`--credential-description` is optional but if you don't pass one it will be blank on the UI which is not nice.

Further info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/credential?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: The commands need to be used with caution. If you have configured multiple secrets in an application, it will all get deleted except the one whose secret you're mentioning in the `--password` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for catching this, good point. In my case I only had one so didn't try with multiple. In any case with azure CLI commands is best to test before doing it production env.

Answer (score -1):

It can't be changed unfortunately, not even by manipulating your App registration **manifest** directly (that's how you change most things that are not supported with their UI).

Great, now you have to set a reminder for yourself to update that application in time. If you leave the company there is a good chance the people after you will forget it and break your application from one day to the next..

Very unusual, that client secret supposedly is only known to your server - how exactly does forcing you to change it after 2 years (in which is was evidently unbroken) ANY safer? Now your Azure-operators have to tell your devs/devops the NEW client-secret.. that is a high-senitive information that has to be transferred SOMEHOW - completely unnecessary risk!

That reminds me a bit of companies where you need to change your PW every month. I think at this point in time it is well understood that this actually **lowers** your security, because people are lazy and find all kinds of workarounds, like appending numbers (worst case: the current month) to the password, greatly weakening the password strength overall.

Same if you have to send a new client-secret for one of your clients every year. Sure everyone KNOWs that you are supposed to use a safe channel (as far as that even exists), but this just invites security issues born out of lazyness, stress or simply human error

Well done Microsoft, i feel safer already..

Comment: There is a feedback request to allow for extension of expirations without having to reset the passwords. Please upvote it as it would be a nice way to solve the issue of having to go through all apps using a secret every few years: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c9d2da85-8be2-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

Comment: It's actually a security risk to have secrets that are valid that long. Especially with app registrations, which are heavily used for persistence in Entra ID tenants, it's best practice to have a maximum of 3, better 1 month secret expiration and a proper secret lifecycle management process in place.

Comment: You are right - I#ts better to have a proper process for that. And if you do it would be ok to enforce some stricter rules.
BUT: most companies just don't have that and will handle this (especially the exchange of the token) pretty clumsily. So yeah, in  a world where everyone is a security expert or at least very mindful about those things: I understand that limitation.
In the REAL WORLD (the world we live in) it just creates a Security Risk. People who might not be prepared for that have to fiddly around with configurations/credentials, etc.

Answer (score -1):

There is an Azure Active Directory feedback request to allow for extension of expirations without having to reset the passwords. Please upvote it as it would be a nice way to solve the issue of having to go through all apps using a Client Secret every few years.

Azure DevOps allows for this on your Personal Access Tokens (PAT). Would love for this to work the same way and allow for extensions in both the CLI as well as the portal:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/c9d2da85-8be2-ec11-a81b-6045bd7ac9f9

Answer (score -1):

From a security best practices standpoint, you should never, ever use an expiration that long. The longer the secret stays the same, the higher the risk of credential loss becomes.
Use 3 month or better 1 month expiration, implement a secret lifecycle management process and when possible always use certificates, better managed identities to avoid service principals/app registrations completely.

Comment: Managed Identities ARE service principals, they just manage themselves and create their own certificates, so you're not actually avoiding service principals completely

Comment: That is unfortunately not correct @Klors. First of all, there are no service principals in Azure, only App Registrations and Enterprise Applications. Managed Identities are represented as Enterprise Applications and don't have a respective app registration in the same tenant.
They also don't manage themselves, but are managed by Microsoft and thereby all the maintenance you could/would normally do is not possible and done by a third party. 
Effectively, you are avoiding app registration operations completely, which is the best practice and what I stated above.

Comment: From - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals?tabs=browser#service-principal-object

Comment: My definition is how it is implemented in Azure, if you read that from the docs or not doesn't change the implementation. Fact is, there are no service principals in Azure and my definition was exactly how Microsoft will explain it to tech savvy users and confusing a managed identity with a app registration is just wrong. The name service principal from the documentation is just for the people who have a hard time understanding the concept. My comment from above represents the implementation of the product, just if anyone else comes across this thread.

Comment: Microsoft refers to service prinicpals throughout its security/AD documentation, so denying that Managed Identities are service principals is MORE confusing

Comment: If it is more confusing for YOU, it's fine, but it's in fact wrong and this site should provide technical guidance for people that read this in the future, so staying factual is generally preferred.

Comment: I know the technical implementation, which is why I wrote the reply. You clearly don't, so please stop confusing people who find this thread in the future.